# how to manage a stack of UITableViews without a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iPhone development, and I am working on modifications to an existing iPhone app. The high-level overview of the issue is this.

I have a button displaying a pop-up containing a UITableView.

I'd like to click on a menu item and display a second UITableView with sub-items, including a back option. If the user clicks back, they go the original UITableView. If the sub-item has additional sub-items underneath it, it should (when clicked) launch another UITableView with these options. There is also a back button as a menu item that will allow the user to navigate to the previous menu displayed.

The challenge here is that I am not using a navigation controller. the original developer only wants to add UITable Views to the stack, add transitions between them as you go from one menu to the other. Most of the tutorials I have seen and tried utilize a navigation controller and Interface Builder to associate the UITableViews.

Right now, I have an XML data source populating the menu, and when I click on a menu item, the titles change correctly, but still uses the same UITableView to display the options - this has consequences of course, as some of the sub-items may not fit on a screen.

any thoughts on how this can be done? I can post some code if necessary, although I think the general description should be able to ring a bell with one of you smart guys!

Comment: I don't quite get why you are trying to duplicate the functionality of the navigation controller. Also, are you trying to control multiple UITableViews using one controller?

Comment: The challenge is that UI doesn't look like the traditional navigation controller look and feel.  It actually looks like a balloon containing a UITableView in it. Clicking on it should navigate to another UITableView. In most examples I've seen the NavigationController uses the entire space, with either grouped or standard UITableViews in it.

Comment: And yes, trying to control multiple UITableViews. One tutorial that I am following for example is at http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/77008/uitableview-drill-down-table-view-tutorial/.

Comment: Another note is that the "back" button is built into the navigation controller...I want to be able to independently place whereever as a standard button. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in numerous ways.

1. I haven't done this first one, but you can probably create a UINavigationController and set its view to the appropriate frame (inside the bubble) hide the navigation bar and set the action of your back button to pop the current view controller.
2. Another method is to have multiple tableviews on one controller, the delegate and datasource methods have the UITableView as an argument so you can distinguish them when setting the height of your rows, headers etc and when returning a UITableViewCell.
3. The way I've chosen to deal with such configurations is to have one UITableView and have only the datasource change. When you reload, insert, delete rows or reload the whole table, you can change anything you want depending on the current datasource level. The easiest none animated way is to reload the whole table.

   a) If your "options" go off-screen height wise (you want fixed height) table change the - (CGFloat)tableview:(UITableView *)table heightForRowAtSection:(NSInteger)section return value

   b) If your "options" go off-screen length wise either make your cell's default textLabel flexible: cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 14; or have custom cells (lookup subclassing UITableViewCell, which is recommended) for each datasource level.

   - If you subclass TableViewCells remember to have different dequeue cell identifiers for each level, so the table doesn't provide you with another level's cell class.

For the "stack" of tableviews or datasources, you can have an NSMutableArray with addObject for push and removeLastObject for pop.
For animations, UITableViews can animate their rows/sections for 3. (see documentation for insert, delete, reload - Rows/Sections UITableView class reference), for 2. you can even have UIView (if not CoreAnimation as Grimless suggested) animations, that move the current tableview to the left (setFrame:) and the next tableview from the right (setFrame offscreen before animation and then in place in the beginAnimation-commitAnimation clause), but make sure you add the tableviews in a container view (the bubble interior) that clips its subviews.

Comment: wow! nice detail. I'll see if I can work on it from here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oi.  This is gonna be a tough one.  My suggestion would be to maintain your own stack implementation.  Then, use CoreAnimation to add/remove UITableViews from your main view controller to get animated effects.  So whenever the user clicks on an element in the current table view, the appropriate controller creates a new controller and table view, and then your custom navigation controller pushes the old one onto the stack, removes the old table view from the main view, sets the new controller as the current one, and adds the new table view to the main view.  Kinda messy, but I think it will work.